# How to use different font sizes on a single label in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to achieve this particular result down here[image]

I've come across different result but not great. i tried to use split() to separate, then set font sizes the bring them back together again. its a long process and i'ld like to do a better job.
please anyone with an idea of how to solve this should help me please.

Comment: Could you give more details about which part to enlarge and which part to another color? And in general, you can cut your strings and bind them to [spans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label#formatted-text)

Comment: XF Label supports both HTML and spans

Comment: it's an amount, so i want the strings before the first comma to be small, then the next strings after comma and before dot (.) should be big, then the remaining strings to be red in color and small in size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Jason said, both `FormattedText` and `HTML` work.

For `FormattedText`, you could check the MS docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label#formatted-text

For HTML, displaying HTML in a Label is limited to the HTML tags that are supported by the underlying platform. And in XAML, HTML strings can become unreadable due to additionally escaping the < and > symbols.

I suggest to use the **`HTML Label Plugin`**.

NuGet Package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.HtmlLabel

xaml:

```
  <htmlLabel:HtmlLabel x:Name="htmlLabel" />
```

Code hebind:

```
 htmlLabel.Text = "<span  style='color: green'><small>N52,</small></span><span style='color:green'><big>O3O.</big></span><span style='color:red'><small>60</small></span>";
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Do not forget add the code beow in your MainActivity.

```
 HtmlLabelRenderer.Initialize();
```

**UPDATED:**

```
   string NO1 = "N52,";
        string NO2 = "O3O.";
        string NO3 = "60";
        htmlLabel.Text = "<span  style='color: green'><small>" + NO1 + "</small></span><span style='color:green'><big>" + NO2 + "</big></span><span style='color:red'><small>"+NO3+"</small></span>";
```

Comment: but this string is not fixed as I'll be getting the digit through an API which means 4digits can come and 6 or more digits can come as well

Comment: how do i go about that?

Comment: I have updated my reply. You could set the digit which you get from the API into the string and then add it into the Text of htmlLabel. But you need to know how many strings you get from the API.

Comment: @DevLayi If this reply help you to solve this issue, please do not forget to accpet as answer. Thanks~

Comment: Thanks. the answer was helpful and it works fine

Answer (score 4):

You can use FormattedString.

For a fixed number of text chunks
Xaml

```
<Label>
   <Label.FormattedText>
      <FormattedString>
         <Span Text="{Binding chunk1}" TextColor="Green" FontSize="10"/>
         <Span Text="{Binding chunk2}" TextColor="Green" FontSize="15"/>
         <Span Text="{Binding chunk3}" TextColor="Red" FontSize="10"/>
      </FormattedString>
   </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

If your number of text chunks are not fixed.

```
<Label FormattedText="{Binding TextChunks}" />
```

ViewModel

```
public FormattedString TextChunks
{
   get
   {
      return new FormattedString
      {
         //You can add a loop here any many as the number of text chunks
         Spans = 
         {
            new Span { Text = "chunk1", TextColor=Color.Green, FontSize = 10 },
            new Span { Text = "chunk2", TextColor=Color.Red, FontSize = 15 },
            new Span { Text = "chunk3", TextColor=Color.Green, FontSize = 10},
            new Span { Text = "chunk4", TextColor=Color.Red , FontSize = 15},
            new Span { Text = "chunk5", TextColor=Color.Green, FontSize = 18},
         }
      }
   }
}
```